# Android - Titlebar and Actionbar is gone after inflate xml for custom list items

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-actionbar

I wanted to create a List with custom Items. Therefore I created a new *list_item.xml* like in this tutorial:
http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/03/watsapp-custom-listview-imageview-textview-baseadapter.html

In my *activity_main.xml* it is shown like this in Android Studio:

[image: screenshot1]

But in the emulator it is shown like that without the titleBar and the actionBar is also missing:

[image: screenshot2]

My *list_item.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:contentDescription="desc"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alias"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_pic"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/public_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alias"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profile_pic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="txt"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/alias"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My *activity_main.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_locked"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_lock" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/contact_list" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The other code like the custom adapter is like in the tutorial with the difference of some renamed variables/ids. Also my *MainActivity.java* extends AppCompatActivity except Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Layout, For toolbar to be shown inside Coordinator Layout,
 it must be inside AppBarLayout(which in turn must be first Child of CL)

The Remaining Content Views can be any Layout with ScrollFlags

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        <AppbarLayout>
               <toolbar>
         </AppBarLayout>
    //Main Content View
    <RelativeLayout 
        app:scroll_flags = "@string/scrollingBehaviour"-->this is important`
 </RelativeLayout>
```